# Google Calendar API: error «Calendar usage limits exceeded»

Tags: calendar, google-calendar-api

**Problems**

As part of my task to provide the ability to manage events via the Google Calendar API. Events use two groups of guests (attendees):
- Group 1 is Google accounts with alternative mail from the same domain (for example site.com)
- Group 2 is person with email all around the world.

This may be a conference call with the participation of 3-10 people, and the annual meeting of about 100 guests. On all events there can be representatives from both groups.

But I am faced with a restriction on the use of the API, which does not allow us to accomplish this task. I managed to find out the cause of this error and reduce the data to analyze the problem to a minimum.

**Workflow and mechanism**

Group 1: Each Google Calendar user is a separate personal Google account with setting “Alternative emails” from the same domain. They have an additional shared calendar for these events, with email notification enabled.

Group 2: This is person with email all around the world, that may have an Google Calendar Account or do not, which are used as the Guest ID for the event.

The organizer (group 1) has an authorized valid access token. He creates an event with a the list of guests. As the guest ID is used Calendar_ID account.

At first, the event was successfully saved correctly and the notification was received for external participants successfully, without errors. But after several repetitions of creating events similar in parameters, an error began to occur. I get the Calendar usage limits exceeded error:
{"error": {"errors": [{"domain": "usageLimits", "reason": "quotaExceeded", "message": "Calendar usage limits exceeded."}], "code": 403, "message ":" Calendar usage limits exceeded. "}}

Although if you save the event only for yourself in own calendar_id without any participants, the following error does not occur!

I have processed enough materials and similar problems from sites:
- https://developers.google.com/calendar/support
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-calendar-api
- https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/calendar
There are several pages indicating a similar problem, but there are no specific solutions or workarounds.

And I see only one real reason for the appearance of such a restriction:
https://support.google.com/a/answer/2905486?hl=en
"Sending too many invitations or emails to external guests". Perhaps I have reached this limit of 100-300. But what to do with it?

**Additional investigation**

For the tests I have created a completely new test environment:
1. A separate Google user has been created as an organizer, with his own calendar and additional calendar.
2. Created a separate Google user as a guest for the event, with your calendar and additional calendar
3. All creation of events was used via web calendar.google.com interface.

As result: 
- An additional attendee's calendar has reached the limit after creating the 4th event, within 5 minutes
- The main calendar - after creating the 15th event, within 15 minutes

I got a restriction that I should try to create an event later. Perhaps there is some kind of limiter on the frequency of creating/updating an event, but nowhere is this mantioned.

With a break of 4 hours, I was able to create only 5 events for the main calendar, I could not add an additional event to the additional calendar due to an error.

**Questions**
1. How do I get around these calendar blocking restrictions? In addition, all guests receive this event as desired and are clearly ready to confirm receipt of such events (subscribe to events from certain organizers).

2. Is it possible to perform this task using G Suite solution or another similar?
3. Could you please provide me with some an extended documentation on the API of the Calendar about:

   - conditions for calendar limitation exceeded (I have not found these criterias for using the API of the Calendar on the official website and pages of official forums)
   - time to unlock to save/update the event, after the occurrence of "Calendar usage limits"

Thanks in advance for your rapid reply as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [support page:](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2905486?hl=en),

> **Calendar usage limits exceeded.** This is the result of an API call. (Don't mix this up with the message "Daily quota exceeded," which points to [insufficient API quota](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/pricing).)

It also means that the user reached one of the Google Calendar limits in place to protect Google users and infrastructure from abusive behavior. [(Reference.)](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/errors#403_calendar_usage_limits_exceeded)

> Suggested actions:
>
> - Read more on the Calendar usage limits in the [G Suite Administrator help](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2905486?hl=en).
> - If one user is making a lot of requests on behalf of many users of a G Suite domain, consider using a [Service Account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount) with authority delegation (setting the [quotaUser parameter](https://developers.google.com/console/help/new/#cappingusage)).
> - Use [exponential backoff](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/errors#exponential-backoff).